# Is it possible to generate ER diagram from Excel file

Tags: mysql, excel, csv, wamp, erd

I just started to work with big dataset. I have Excel file, and i want to import it in a Mysql database on Wamp. There is option to import data from csv file to database table, but i want to know is there any tool for generating ER diagram from that csv file, or that have to be done manualy.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

[Mysql](http://www.mysql.com/products/workbench/) wb could help for ER from mySql.

[Create Database Model](http://office.microsoft.com/en-in/visio-help/create-a-database-model-also-known-as-entity-relationship-diagram-HA010115477.aspx) could help for generating ERs from excel.

Hope it helps. Thanks

Comment: I am familliar with reverse engineering, but i don't know how is it possible to import csv file into database , or we must create tabele and than inport csv file.